# running multiple models using for-loop in r

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm trying to run a loop which generates 5 random samples, and then 5 different RandomForest models.

I getting troubles over the second part (running the models); I can't approach the dependent variable (`nam$eR` in the following code):

```
numS <- 5 # number of samples
dataS <- ERC3
rfModels <- list()

for(j in 1:numS) {

print(j)
set.seed(j+1)
nam <- paste("RFs", j, sep = "")
assign(nam, dataS[sample(nrow(dataS),100000),]) # Random sample of 100,000 rows.

namM <- paste("RFfit", j, sep = "")
assign(namM, randomForest(as.factor(nam$eR)~., data=nam[,-231], importance = TRUE))

rfModels[[j]] <- namM

}
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if this will work exactly for your case since I don't have sample data, but if you were to do what I'm thinking you are looking for with the `mtcars` data set, it would be something like this...First, it might be best to have a list of data frames to house the data you are running the model on. This can be done as follows:

```
library(dplyr)
library(randomForest)

dfs <- list() #home for the list of dataframes on which to run a randomforest

set.seed(1)
for(i in 1:5){
  dfs[[i]] <- sample_n(mtcars, size = 10, replace = FALSE)
}
```

(Per the comments, a slicker way to do this would be to go with

```
  dfs_slicker_approach <- lapply(seq(5), 
                                 function(i) sample_n(mtcars, size = 10, replace = FALSE))
```

)

The `dfs` list now contains a list of `data.frames` which contain 10 randomly selected rows from the `mtcars` data set. (Obviously, you'll want to update this to fit your needs.)

Then we run the `randomForest` function on this list using the `lapply` function as follows:

```
rfs <- lapply(dfs, function(m) randomForest(mpg ~ ., 
                                            data = m, importance = TRUE ))
```

Again, change the syntax to select the columns you are interested in predicting on. The `rfs` list now contains all of our `randomForest` objects. You can again access these using `lapply`. For instnace, if we want the predicted values, we can do this as follows: (We'll subset to only the first set of predictions to avoid printing a a lot of info)

```
> lapply(rfs, as.data.frame(predict))[1]
[[1]]
                       value
Merc 230            22.85464
Merc 450SE          17.61810
Fiat 128            22.31571
Porsche 914-2       23.95909
Valiant             21.28786
Pontiac Firebird    15.93824
Ford Pantera L      21.20373
Chrysler Imperial   14.40740
Lincoln Continental 16.43074
Mazda RX4 Wag       21.18467
```

Comment: I probably missed something; how do you run over the 5 data sets? And.. can you please tell me what the part of function(m).. tks!

Comment: `lapply` lets us apply a function on each element in a list. We made a list of data frames which we called `dfs` and then used `lapply` on that list to hit each data frame with the `randomForest(mpg ~ . , data = m, importance = TRUE)` function. In this case, `m` is just a place holder/bookkeeping tool so we know that we are passing each full data frame element from our `dfs` list to the `data=` argument of `randomForest`.

Comment: great answer-Tks.. I wrote the following line: `lapply(dataL, function(m) randomForest(as.factor(eR) ~ ., 
                                            data = m[,-231], importance = TRUE ))` but it tells me _ Error in is.factor(x) : object 'eR' not found_. Can you help me with that..

Comment: Try: `lapply(dataL, function(m) randomForest(as.factor(m$eR) ~ ., data = m[,-231], importance = TRUE ))`. You need to use the `m` here again since you are referring to a column in the data frames you are passing `lapply`.

Comment: seems to work (it starts running--probably will take a day or two) - Thank you very much for your help and patience.

Comment: No need to initialize `rfs` if assigning to `lapply` and `dfs` could be assigned to an `lapply` call.

Comment: Thanks, @Parfait, you are 100% correct. That was an unnecessary call; removing the line now.

Comment: And consider: `dfs <- lapply(seq(5), function(i) sample_n(mtcars, size = 10, replace = FALSE))`

Comment: Using `lapply` to generate the list of data frames used in the modeling is a much slicker solution, to be sure. I'll add that in as an alternative approach. Lots of good suggestions-thank you.

Answer (score 2):

While not deviating from Nick's solution, here is an approach using the [`tidyverse` workflow](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/).  Highlights are: readable code via pipes, using `dplyr` verbs and `purrr` functionals and keeping data, models and predictions in a nice tidy tibble.

```
library(randomForest)
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(42)

analysis <- rerun(5, sample_n(mtcars, size = 10, replace = FALSE)) %>% 
  tibble(data = .) %>% 
  rownames_to_column("model_number") %>% 
  mutate(models = map(data, ~randomForest(mpg ~ ., data = .x, importance = TRUE))) %>% 
  mutate(predict = map(models, ~predict(.x)))
```

You can then get what you want when you need it....

```
comparison <-  analysis %>% 
mutate(actual = map(data, "mpg")) %>% 
unnest(predict, actual)

comparison

# A tibble: 50 × 3
   model_number  predict actual
          <chr>    <dbl>  <dbl>
1             1 14.10348   14.7
2             1 16.78987   15.0
3             1 15.14636   17.3
4             1 15.81265   15.5
5             1 24.11492   21.5
6             1 24.24701   22.8
7             1 15.84953   10.4
8             1 21.72781   32.4
9             1 21.78105   21.0
10            1 15.58614   16.4
# ... with 40 more rows
```

... and see the results easily.

```
ggplot(comparison, aes(actual, predict)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~model_number, nrow = 1)
```

[image]

Comment: Very (very!) nice way.. I'll try it. Just one thing- do you think this will be good also for large data sets (say 100,000 observations and more); I'm talking about the visualization part.

Comment: It would get a little messy, but you could look at other methods to reduce the data to a reasonable amount to visually compare.